# Why is "All that remains" banned from Android: Netrunner World Championships?

Tags: android-netrunner, tournament

The Android: Netrunner [tournament rules](https://www.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/android-netrunner/support/FAQ/Android-Netrunner%20Tournament%20Rules.pdf) say the choice of banned cards is up to the tournament organiser.  With the single exception of banning "All That Remains" at world level.

> **Authorized Cards**
>
> All Android: Netrunner cards produced by Fantasy
>   Flight Games are legal for tournament play (unless banned). No other
>   cards or proxy cards are permitted. In North America, cards are legal
>   upon their release. Competitors outside North America should check
>   with their TO to determine which cards are tournament legal.
>   Exception: All That Remains is not legal for the World Championships

What's so special about "All That Remains"?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**There is nothing banned in All That Remains.**

This exception was added in the update to the Tournament Rules for the World Championship to clarify that because it was being released so close to the Championship, it would not be legal (since players would not be able to adequately play with it first).

I expect this exception to be removed in the next update now that the World Championship has concluded.

Comment: Is there a source link?

Comment: @AndrewVandever Well the rules themselves are linked in the question. I don't have an official source for my answer though, but it seems to be widely believed in the community (especially because the entire pack was banned, rather than specific cards). When the next update to the tournament rules comes out, that might confirm this answer (since presumably this exception will be removed).